# Most elegant way to check sessionStorage support?

Tags: javascript

I have a cookie checker function, which storage a value variable in the var 'cookie1'.
And a sessionStorage storage cookie.

```
if (cookie1 == '9oz' | sessionStorage.getItem('sessionstoragecookie1') == '9oz')
{
    // execute code 1
}
else
{
    // execute code 2
}
```

But sessionStorage is not supported in IE6 and IE7. So it throws an error and breaks the entire script. I could do something like this, but this is absolutely not elegant. What is the most elegant way to work this around?

```
if (cookie1 == '9oz')
{
    // execute code 1
}
else
{
    if (typeof(sessionStorage) !='undefined')
    {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('sessionstoragecookie1') == '9oz')
        {
            // execute code 1
        }
        else
        {
            // execute code 2
        }
    }

    else
        {
            // execute code 2
        }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if (cookie1 === '9oz' || (window.sessionStorage && window.sessionStorage.getItem('sessionstoragecookie1') === '9oz')) {
    // you've got a 9oz reference 
} else {
    // you haven't :(
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this part `&& window.sessionStorage.getItem('sessionstoragecookie1') == '9oz' ` will throw a object or method is not supported in Internet Explorer 6/7.

Comment: @user900973: Shouldn't do, because I first check that window.sessionStorage exists; and that code will only execute if it does.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(typeof(sessionStorage) == 'undefined')
{
    sessionStorage = {
        getItem: function(){},
        setItem: function(){},
        clear: function(){},
        removeItem: function(){}
    };
}
```

And now use as usual. It will always return NULL

But I would consider this script

http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

This will enable sessionStorage in every browser.

Comment: technically need to define : clear & removeItem as well if you are going to mock the storage api

Answer (score 6):

I would use try/catch to check if the browser supports sessionStorage.

```
function isSessionStorageSupported() {
    try {
      var storage = window.sessionStorage;
      storage.setItem('test', 'test');
      storage.removeItem('test');    
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
 if (isSessionStorageSupported()) {
   // do something with it
 } else {
  // have a fallback code here
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me when I moved the `var storage...` line into the try/catch block. Any of the other answers here which involved `window.sessionStorage` outside of a try/catch block produced the error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document` for me.

Comment: how to test it?

Comment: @YatinMistry You will need to mock it. Some examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485420/how-to-mock-localstorage-in-javascript-unit-tests

Answer (score 3):

```
function checkSessionStorage()
{
   return window.sessionStorage;
}
```

If it is `undefined` then `sessionStorage` is not supported.

Comment: What's the benefit for the code above to use this instead of `if (typeof(sessionStorage) !='undefined')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
What it does is that if a browser doesn't support sessionStorage, it clears the session.

```
try { 
   sessionStorage.setItem('name','value'); 
}
catch(e){
if(e.code == 22){ 
   sessionStorage.clear(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I have a few useful functions I cooked up and threw into a file named 'manage_storage.js'. I hope they are as useful to you guys, as they have served me well.

Here is my code:

```
/* Conditional Function checks a web browser for 'session storage' support. [BEGIN] */

if (typeof isSessStorageAllowed !== 'function')
    {
        function isSessStorageAllowed()
            {
                if (!!window.sessionStorage && typeof sessionStorage.getItem === 'function' && typeof sessionStorage.setItem === 'function' && typeof sessionStorage.removeItem === 'function')
                    {
                        try
                            {
                                var cur_dt = new Date();
                                var cur_tm = cur_dt.getTime();
                                var ss_test_itm_key = 'ss_test_itm_' + String(cur_tm);
                                var ss_test_val = 'ss_test_val_' + String(cur_tm);

                                sessionStorage.setItem(ss_test_itm_key, String(ss_test_val));

                                if (sessionStorage.getItem(ss_test_itm_key) == String(ss_test_val))
                                    {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        return false;
                                    };

                                sessionStorage.removeItem(ss_test_itm_key);
                            }
                        catch (exception)
                            {
                                return false;
                            };
                    }
                else
                    {
                        return false;
                    };
            };
    };

/* Conditional Function checks a web browser for 'session storage' support. [END] */

/* Conditional Function checks a web browser for 'local storage' support. [BEGIN] */

if (typeof isLclStorageAllowed !== 'function')
    {
        function isLclStorageAllowed()
            {
                if (!!window.localStorage && typeof localStorage.getItem === 'function' && typeof localStorage.setItem === 'function' && typeof localStorage.removeItem === 'function')
                    {
                        try
                            {
                                var cur_dt = new Date();
                                var cur_tm = cur_dt.getTime();
                                var ls_test_itm_key = 'ls_test_itm_' + String(cur_tm);
                                var ls_test_val = 'ls_test_val_' + String(cur_tm);

                                localStorage.setItem(ls_test_itm_key, String(ls_test_val));

                                if (localStorage.getItem(ls_test_itm_key) == String(ls_test_val))
                                    {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        return false;
                                    };

                                localStorage.removeItem(ls_test_itm_key);
                            }
                        catch (exception)
                            {
                                return false;
                            };
                    }
                else
                    {
                        return false;
                    };
            };
    };

/* Conditional Function checks a web browser for 'local storage' support. [END] */

/* Conditional Function checks a web browser for 'web storage' support. [BEGIN] */

/* Prerequisites: 'isSessStorageAllowed()', 'isLclStorageAllowed()' */

if (typeof isWebStorageAllowed !== 'function')
    {
        function isWebStorageAllowed()
            {
                if (isSessStorageAllowed() === true && isLclStorageAllowed() === true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        return false;
                    };
            };
    };

/* Conditional Function checks a web browser for 'web storage' support. [END] */
```