# How to mock web sql with qunit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cordova, tdd, qunit

I'm trying to figure out how to mock web sql with qunit. Yes, I know web sql is deprecated, but it's what phonegap uses.

I'm already mocking localstorage commands like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381941/1665818

But I also need to mock queries to the database. What's the best way to do this?

### Update (4/14/14)

Since I couldn't find anything, I started building a web sql mocking framework here if anyone wants to contribute: https://github.com/aharris88/websql-mock