# How do I configure jsdom with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

I have installed jest and jsdom into my react project but I am having problems with importing a react component that uses the `window.localStorage` variable. I have added a setup file for jsdom that I believed would solve the problem.

Here is my setup:

jest config in package.json

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost:8080/Dashboard/index.html",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "node_modules/react/",
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "es6"
    ]
  }
```

setup.js

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';

const DEFAULT_HTML = '<html><body></body></html>';

global.document = jsdom.jsdom(DEFAULT_HTML);

global.window = document.defaultView;
global.navigator = window.navigator;
global.localStorage = window.localStorage;
```

test.js

```
'use strict';
import setup from './setup';
import React from 'react';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import Reportlet from '../components/Reportlet.jsx';

it('Ensures the react component renders', () => {

});
```

My reportlet component uses the localStorage variable but yells:

`Cannot read property getItem of undefined` when I call `localStorage.getItem(<some item>)`

I read [here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-jquery.html#docsNav) that jest comes shipped with jsdom but I am not sure if I need the extra jsdom dependency or not. I also read [here](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html) that jsdom needs to be loaded before requiring react for the first time.

Does anyone know how to configure jest with jsdom correctly?

Comment: jsdom does not support localStorage. Looks like you can use a node-friendly stub like 'node-localstorage' - See bottom of comments at https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1137  , or you can mock it with something like https://github.com/letsrock-today/mock-local-storage or  roll your own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485420/how-to-mock-localstorage-in-javascript-unit-tests

Comment: Ahh I see that it is specific to missing functionality in jsdom. I solved my problem by using your suggested solution of node-localstorage. If you format this as an answer I would gladly accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll repost as an answer when I'm back at my machine (on phone now). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsdom does not support localStorage. It looks like you can use a node-friendly stub like 'node-localstorage'. See bottom of comments at https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1137

...or you can mock it with something like https://github.com/letsrock-today/mock-local-storage

...or roll your own mock like seen here: [How to mock localStorage in JavaScript unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485420/how-to-mock-localstorage-in-javascript-unit-tests)