# How to "mock" navigator.geolocation in a React Jest Test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to write tests for a react component I've built that utilizes `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` within a method like so (rough example of my component):

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  method() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
       ...code...
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(...)
  }

}
```

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), which includes a test:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});
```

This test fails, printing out this in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined
```

I'm new to React, but have quite a bit of experience with angular 1.x. In angular it is common to mock out (within the tests in a beforeEach) functions, "services", and global object methods like navigator.geolocation.etc. I spent time researching this issue and this bit of code is the closest I could get to a mock:

```
global.navigator = {
  geolocation: {
    getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
  }
}
```

I put this in my test file for App, but it had no effect.

How can I "mock" out this navigator method and get the test to pass?

EDIT: I looked into using a library called [geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolocation) which supposedly wraps `navigator.getCurrentPosition` for use in a node environment. If I understand correctly, jest runs tests in a node environment and uses JSDOM to mock out things like `window`. I haven't been able to find much information on JSDOM's support of `navigator`. The above mentioned library did not work in my react app. Using the specific method getCurrentPosition would only return undefined even though the library itself was imported correctly and available within the context of the App class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure jsdom with jest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709386/how-do-i-configure-jsdom-with-jest)

Comment: @jordan, could you explain why you think it's a duplicate? I looked into that answer and tried to fix this issue by using the [geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolocation) library, which is a similar solution to the "node-friendly stub like 'node-localstorage'." solution described. But within the context of my app, the `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returned undefined, not sure why it doesn't work. An actual explanation of how to go about solving this specific issue would be far more helpful.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It appears that there is already a `global.navigator` object and, like you, I wasn't able to reassign it.

I found that mocking the geolocation part and adding it to the existing `global.navigator` worked for me.

```
const mockGeolocation = {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn(),
  watchPosition: jest.fn()
};

global.navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation;
```

I added this to a `src/setupTests.js` file as described here - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests#initializing-test-environment

Comment: When I tried your solution I have this error : 
'TypeError: Cannot set property 'geolocation' of undefined'
I tried to defined it like that :
"global.navigator = {
 userAgent: 'node.js'
};"
And I have this error "ReferenceError: initialize is not defined". I don't know what to do to resolve that. Do you have an idea of what to do in my situation ?

Comment: This solution is still working for me.  Make sure you define it in `src/setupTests.js` https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#initializing-test-environment

Comment: Latest documentation can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#initializing-test-environment

Answer (score 31):

I know this issue might have been solved, but seems that all the solutions above are all wrong, at least for me.

When you do this mock: `getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()`
it returns undefined, if you want to return something, this is the correct implementation:

```
const mockGeolocation = {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce((success) => Promise.resolve(success({
      coords: {
        latitude: 51.1,
        longitude: 45.3
      }
    })))
};
global.navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation;
```

I am using create-react-app

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Great! Thank you for that! But do you also know how to trigger the `error` function?

Comment: with TS, it gives an error: "Cannot assign to 'geolocation' because it is a read-only property."

Comment: @GreatQuestion for the read- only restriction, I believe it is a TypeScript restriction, a potential work around is to disable the Type on that particular line.. As mentioned it's a work around I got my solution from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712640/jest-testing-window-location-reload

Answer (score 8):

A TypeScript version for anyone that was getting
`Cannot assign to 'geolocation' because it is a read-only property.`

In the `mockNavigatorGeolocation.ts` file (this can live in a `test-utils` folder or similar)

```
export const mockNavigatorGeolocation = () => {
  const clearWatchMock = jest.fn();
  const getCurrentPositionMock = jest.fn();
  const watchPositionMock = jest.fn();

  const geolocation = {
    clearWatch: clearWatchMock,
    getCurrentPosition: getCurrentPositionMock,
    watchPosition: watchPositionMock,
  };

  Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, 'geolocation', {
    value: geolocation,
  });

  return { clearWatchMock, getCurrentPositionMock, watchPositionMock };
};
```

I then import this in my test at the top of the file:

```
import { mockNavigatorGeolocation } from '../../test-utils';
```

And then use the function like so:

```
const { getCurrentPositionMock } = mockNavigatorGeolocation();
getCurrentPositionMock.mockImplementation((success, rejected) =>
  rejected({
    code: '',
    message: '',
    PERMISSION_DENIED: '',
    POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: '',
    TIMEOUT: '',
  })
);
```

Comment: If I run `npm test`, it throws an error: 'TypeError: Cannot redefine property: geolocation
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)'

Comment: try adding `configurable: true` to the options object in `Object.defineProperty`

Answer (score 5):

Mocking with `setupFiles`

```
// __mocks__/setup.js

jest.mock('Geolocation', () => {
  return {
    getCurrentPosition: jest.fn(),
    watchPosition: jest.fn(),
  }
});
```

and then in your `package.json`

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "setupFiles": [
    "./__mocks__/setup.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I followed @madeo's comment above to mock `global.navigator.geolocation`. It worked!

Additionally I did the following to mock `global.navigator.permissions`:

```
  global.navigator.permissions = {
    query: jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ state: 'granted' })),
  };
```

Set `state` to any of `granted`, `denied`, `prompt` as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, I did not have the global.navigator object defined, so I had to specify it in my setupTests.js file

```
const mockGeolocation = {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn(),
  watchPosition: jest.fn(),
}
global.navigator = { geolocation: mockGeolocation }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to actually use spy in this case to avoid assigning to readonly property if you are using typescript.

```
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended'

jest
  .spyOn(global.navigator.geolocation, 'getCurrentPosition')
  .mockImplementation((success) =>
    Promise.resolve(
      success({
        ...mock<GeolocationPosition>(),
        coords: {
          ...mock<GeolocationCoordinates>(),
          latitude: 51.1,
          longitude: 45.3,
        },
      }),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Added to the above answers, if you want to update navigator.permissions, this will work.The key here is to mark `writable as true` before mocking

```
Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, "permissions", {
   writable: true,
   value: {
    query : jest.fn()
    .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ state: 'granted' }))
   },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this myself using Vitest and TypeScript. You can simply replace vitest (vi) with jest. I needed to mock the user accepting the request for their location. This was my solution:

```
// Mock the geolocation object
const mockedGeolocation = {
    getCurrentPosition: vi.fn((success, _error, _options) => {
        success({
            coords: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                accuracy: 0,
            },
        });
    }),
    watchPosition: vi.fn(),
};
//Overwrite the properties on naviagtor
Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, "geolocation", {
    writable: true,
    value: mockedGeolocation,
});

Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, "permissions", {
    writable: true,
    value: {
        query: vi
            .fn()
            .mockImplementation(() =>
                Promise.resolve({ state: "granted" }),
            ),
    },
})
```