# Jest: Testing window.location.reload

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How do I write a test that makes sure that the method `reloadFn` does in fact reload the window? I found [this resource](https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/5cb571a13a6635ab89cf2bb47dc004a3) but I am unclear on how to expect a window reload when writing a test when that window reload happens in a given function. Thanks for the help!

```
const reloadFn = () => {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: most assert libraries include helper functions that help determine how many times a function has been called so your test could call it and then check that it was called the appropriate amount of times. see: https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies/ ```expect(spy).to.have.been.called.exactly(3);```

Comment: I feel like with unit testing you just need to make sure that that function got called and expect window.location.reload to function correctly. You wouldn't typically test that a window actually got reloaded, just that reload was called

Comment: For TypeScript, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61649798/1724702)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Updated Answer (November 2021)

Package:
`"jest": "^26.6.0"`
`"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4"`

Build: `create-react-app 4`

```js
describe("test window location's reload function", () => {
  const original = window.location;

  const reloadFn = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  };

  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      configurable: true,
      value: { reload: jest.fn() },
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', { configurable: true, value: original });
  });

  it('mocks reload function', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(window.location.reload)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('calls reload function', () => {
    reloadFn(); // as defined above..
    expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

##### Note: Updated answer because the the `old answer` wasn't supported with latest jest version used in CRA.

---

### Old answer

Here’s the solution but refactored for better organization:

```
describe('test window location\'s reload function', () => {
  const { reload } = window.location;

  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'reload', {
      configurable: true,
    });
    window.location.reload = jest.fn();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    window.location.reload = reload;
  });

  it('mocks reload function', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(window.location.reload)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('calls reload function', () => {
    reloadFn(); // as defined above..
    expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: There must have been a breaking change in one of the versions because this throws `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'reload' of object '[object Location]'` now. I added an answer with a solution I found works (there are other good solutions in this thread too).

Comment: Fixed the above error in my updated answer..

Comment: on jest 29 the number of  calls of jest.fn appears to not be cleared / reset

Answer (score 20):

## If you use TypeScript with Jest:

##### Idea

1. Create a copy and then delete `window`'s `location` property.
2. Now set `location` property with `reload` function mocked.
3. Set the original value back when test completes.

##### Code: TypeScript 3.x and below

```js
const location: Location = window.location;
delete window.location;
window.location = {
    ...location,
    reload: jest.fn()
};

// <code to test>
// <code to test>
// <code to test>

expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
jest.restoreAllMocks();
window.location = location;
```

##### Code: TypeScript 4+

TypeScript 4 has stricter checks (which is a good thing), so I am not really sure if there's a way to do this other than to suppress the error using [`@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) or [`@ts-expect-error`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments).

**WARNING**: Suppressing TypeScript validations can be dangerous.

```js
const location: Location = window.location;

// WARNING:
//     @ts-ignore and @ts-expect-error suppress TypeScript validations by ignoring errors.
//     Suppressing TypeScript validations can be dangerous.

// @ts-ignore
delete window.location;

window.location = {
    ...location,
    reload: jest.fn()
};

// <code to test>
// <code to test>
// <code to test>

expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
jest.restoreAllMocks();
window.location = location;
```

Comment: This is the only solution I found that can be used with typescript. Great work.

Comment: Dude THIS should be the accepted answer as window.location.reload is readonly and not configurable. Great stuff!!

Comment: delete window.location causes an error "The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional" in typescript.

Comment: With jest 26.4.2 and typescript 3.7.2 this was the only answer that worked for me. The currently accepted answer failed to write to assign to `window.location.reload`.

Comment: @Ken I've updated the answer to add code that works on TypeScript 4, but I am afraid I don't have a good solution

Answer (score 15):

You can also simplify Murtaza Hussain's solution to

```
  describe('refreshPage', () => {
    const { reload } = window.location;

    beforeAll(() => {
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
        writable: true,
        value: { reload: jest.fn() },
      });
    });

    afterAll(() => {
      window.location.reload = reload;
    });

    it('reloads the window', () => {
      refreshPage();
      expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Comment: using `writable`  instead of `configurable` got this working for me over Murtaza's answer

Comment: `refreshPage` isn't a function here?

Comment: `refreshPage` isn't a function here?

Answer (score 6):

You could use sessionStorage to save a value for each reload.
As long as the browser does not close, the value will remain in sessionStorage.
When the page reloads the value will increment. Verify the fresh reload with this value.
Test this by pasting reloadFn() into the console.
The console will display Reload count: 1, and increment with each reload.

```
const reloadFn = () => {
  window.location.reload(true);
}

window.onload = function() {
    // get reloadCount from sessionStorage
    reloadCount = sessionStorage.getItem('reloadCount');

    // reloadCount will be null the first page load or a new value for each reload
    if (reloadCount) {
        // increment reloadCount
        reloadCount = parseInt(reloadCount) + 1;
        // save the new value to sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('reloadCount', reloadCount);
        console.log("Reload count: " + reloadCount);
    } else {
        // if reloadCount was null then set it to 1 and save to sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('reloadCount', 1);
        console.log("Page was loaded for the first time");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your function testing `reloadFn`, you should use the mock code you linked to:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'reload', {
    configurable: true,
}); // makes window.location.reload writable
window.location.reload = jest.fn(); // set up the mock
reloadFn(); // this should call your mock defined above
expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled(); // assert the call
window.location.reload.mockRestore(); // restore window.location.reload to its original function
```

For a more improved test, you can use

```
expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
```

Of note is that this is not actually verifying that the window is reloaded which is outside of the scope of a unit test. Something like browser testing or integration testing would verify that.

Comment: According to the official documentation, `mockRestore` only works for mock created with `spyOn`: https://jestjs.io/fr/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using workarounds with `Object.defineProperty` you can use native Jest's `spyOn` function in the following way:

```
test("reload test", () => {
  const { getByText } = renderComponentWithReloadButton()

  const reload = jest.fn()

  jest
    .spyOn(window, "location", "get")
    .mockImplementation(() => ({ reload } as unknown as Location))

  // Call an action that should trigger window.location.reload() function
  act(() => {
    getByText("Reload me").click()
  })

  // Test if `reload` function was really called
  expect(reload).toBeCalled()
})
```

Also make sure you clear the mock after test by using for example `jest.clearAllMocks()` function.

Comment: I get a runtime error of ` Property location does not have access type get`

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking this up in 2020, well i had the same issued.

**Why is the problem happening for some and not for others?**

Well it all depends on the version of chrome you are running, i wrote    a test for a component that eventually called `window.location.reload`. Below is the section of the component code:

```
onConfirmChange() {
    const {data, id} = this.state;

    this.setState({showConfirmationModal: false}, () => {
        this.update(data, id)
          .then(() => window.location.reload());
    });
}
```

The test initially failed on my build server with chrome version 71, it was passing for my local with chrome version 79.
I updated my chrome today to version 84, and the problem popped up in my local
The deleting of window.local seems to be un supported. Tried all the solution i could find in google nothing worked.

**What is the solution then?**

It was actually very simple, for react testing my system is using enzyme so what i did was wrapped the `window.location.reload` in an instance method and stubbed that in the test

JSX code:

```
reloadWindow() {
    window.location.reload();
}

onConfirmChange() {
    const {data, id} = this.state;
  
    this.setState({showConfirmationModal: false}, () => {
      this.update(data, id)
        .then(() => reloadWindow());
    });   
}
```

TEST

```
it('check what happened', () => {
    render();
    const component = wrapper.instance();
    sandbox.stub(component, 'reloadWindow').callsFake();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer (May 2021)

I ran into some issues with a lot of the answers in the thread. I think version changes over time to the underlying libraries caused the breakage.

My Config:

- `"typescript": "~4.1.5"`
- `"jest": "^26.6.3"`
- `"jest-environment-jsdom": "^26.6.2"`

Also, I should note, my solution is pretty verbose. But my use case needs to test `window.location.replace()` and the outcome. So I couldn't
simply mock `window.location.replace`. If you just need to mock one of the functions and don't care how the actual `href` changes, then some of the solutions in the thread will work great with less code.

### Working Version

I found that completely polyfilling the `window.location` object solved all my problems.

#### `window.location` polyfill

Use this code and put it anywhere in your test file or setup files:

```js
export class MockWindowLocation {
  private _url: URL = new URL();

  get href (): string {
    return this._url.toString();
  }

  set href (url: string) {
    this._url = new URL(url);
  }

  get protocol (): string {
    return this._url.protocol;
  }

  get host (): string {
    return this._url.host;
  }

  get hostname (): string {
    return this._url.hostname;
  }

  get origin (): string {
    return this._url.origin;
  }

  get port (): string {
    return this._url.port;
  }

  get pathname (): string {
    return this._url.pathname;
  }

  get hash (): string {
    return this._url.hash;
  }

  get search (): string {
    return this._url.search;
  }

  replace = jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
    this.href = url;
  });

  assign = jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
    this.href = url;
  });

  reload = jest.fn();

  toString(): string {
    return this._url.toString();
  }
}
```

#### Test it

Then you have to delete `window.location` and set it to the new polyfill:

```js
  it('should be able to test window.location', () => {
    delete window.location;
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      value: new MockWindowLocation()
    });

    window.location.href = 'https://example.com/app/#/route/1';
    window.location.reload();

    expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(window.location.href).toBe('https://example.com/app/#/route/1');
    expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/app/');
    expect(window.location.hash).toBe('#/route/1');
  });
```

This works wonders for me. Hope it helps someone else out.

### Other answers are simplier

To re-iterate, there are other answers in this thread that work just fine. I found:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
  writable: true,
  value: { reload: jest.fn() },
});
```

And:

```js
const location: Location = window.location;
delete window.location;
window.location = {
  ...location,
  reload: jest.fn()
};
```

both to be helpful. But like I said, I needed to spy on `replace()` and still have the standard functionality of `window.location`.

Hope this helps someone. Cheers!

Comment: did you meet such issue on delete window.location: "The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.ts(2790)"?

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov, I do think I did. But it could be a new typescript or jest version that is causing that. What versions are you using?