i need to mock the reload method of window.location object for testing in jest
i have declared a function named as reloadScreen, which reload the browser window on execution and it gets invoked on clicking a button. Now i want to test this function that on clicking a button window is getting reloaded or not, i am testing in jest.
my html code for button is :
<button class='restartBtn' onclick="reloadScreen()">reset</button>
my javascript function is:
function reloadScreen(){
    window.location.reload();
}

my test code is provided below :
describe('should reload the browser on clicking a button having class as "restartBtn". ', ()=> {

  let restartButton;
  let dom;
  let window;
  let document;

  beforeEach(() => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html,  { runScripts: 'dangerously' });
    document = dom.window.document;
    window = dom.window;

    restartButton = document.querySelector('.restartBtn');
  })

  test('should reload the browser.', ()=>{

    // Mock the reload method of window.location object
    const reloadMock = jest.fn();
    window.location.reload = reloadMock;

    restartButton.click();

    // Expect window.location.reload to be called
    expect(reloadMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

})

error i am getting is,
[error] : reload property of window.location is read-only cannot be modified.
can anyone help me, to resolve this.

It seems like you are using jsdom, seems like this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67711101/21340569
